# Parsing from standard input

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

How do I parse the standard input (without buffering)? If I understand correctly, `phrase/2` needs a list, and `phrase_from_file/2` from `library(pure_input)` needs a file.

I solved my problem using normal predicates (not DCG) and using built-ins like `get_char/2` and `read_line_to_codes/2`, but at the end the implementation looks suspiciously similar to the solution I would have written in C.

And if I can sneak a very much related question: what is standard input in SWI-Prolog? `read_line_to_codes` (`library(readutil)`) needs an input stream (unlike `get/1`, for example). I get it with the following predicate:

```
input_stream(Stream) :-
    current_stream(Object, read, Stream),
    integer(Object).
```

. . . which of course works, but feels a bit hacked. Is it possible to have more than one open input stream? How am I going to know which one is the standard input of the operating system (Linux in my case)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the proper naming of streams. Here a sample that could be useful:

```
?- read_line_to_codes(user_input,L).
|: a line
L = [97, 32, 108, 105, 110, 101].
```

The most detailed explanation page I found is [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.16%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/IO.html%27%29%29).

Comment: I thought I had read this page carefully enough... This answers my standard input question indeed. Still don't know if I can use DCG for parsing standard input.

Comment: yes, use a loop like `repeat, read_line_to_codes(user_input,L), phrase(your_grammar,L).`